# How to write Pydantic Data Model for List is having None object

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic-v2

I am fetching some data from Datadog API and below is the API response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "scalar_response",
      "attributes": {
        "columns": [
          {
            "values": [
              0.07831818181818186
            ],
            "type": "number",
            "meta": {
              "unit": [
                {
                  "family": "cpu",
                  "plural": "cores",
                  "name": "core",
                  "id": 31,
                  "scale_factor": 1.0,
                  "short_name": None
                },
                None
              ]
            },
            "name": "cpu_requested_avg"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Here the **data -> attributes -> columns -> meta -> unit** is a list having None object.

I have defined data model for unit like

```
class SQRMetadataUnit(pydantic.BaseModel):
    """
    Metadata Unit for resulting numerical values in Scaler query response
    See https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#query-scalar-data-across-multiple-products

    Attributes:
        family: Unit family, allows for conversion between units of the same family, for scaling.
        name: Unit name
        plural: Plural form of the unit name.
        scale_factor: Factor for scaling between units of the same family.
        short_name: Abbreviation of the unit.
    """
    id: int
    family: str
    name: str
    plural: str
    scale_factor: float
    short_name: Optional[str] = None

class SQRMetadata(pydantic.BaseModel):
    """
    Metadata for resulting numerical values in Scaler query response
    See https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#query-scalar-data-across-multiple-products

    Attributes:
        unit: Detailed information about the unit.
    """

    unit: List[SQRMetadataUnit] = None
```

I am getting below mentioned error
data.0.attributes.columns.0.meta.unit.1
Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of SQRMetadataUnitWithNone [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]

Already mentioned the option in description.